# magento 2 contact us add multiple recipients

Tags: magento2, contact-us, contact-form, smtp

task:

- create form "contact us"
- send data from the form to 2 Email addresses

I created form but magento 2 does not provide option in admin to add  multiple emails separated by ,

[image]

I was looking for a solution to the problem and found a way: completely rewrite the contact form saveing controller and give it your transport method in which you need to assign the number of additional emails

if someone came across such or similar implementation, please help with an example

**add**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this resolved ?

Comment: Try this patch once - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24984#issuecomment-589525476

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to add multiple email address in this field is same as I do in M1 just remove the `validate-email` class from the field (by inspect element) then add multiple emails , separated. and press save.

Look first class validate-email remove it manually & save with multiple emails:
[image]
It will work, I will look proper free solution for it and post it here. Let me know if its still not working for you.

Comment: if you remove the validation, it will only send to the first mail

Comment: No not at all this validation is not for this purpose. It will send to all emails separated by comma. This validation is just for to enter correct email address

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove validation?

Comment: just inspect element on text box and remove `validate-email` class

Comment: I added 2 screenshots to the question, which show that the sending goes to one whole mail

Comment: This is what you want

Comment: Magento sends not 2 letters per letter to 2 mails, but one letter to one incorrect mail, which looks like this: "support@mage.com info@mage.com"

Comment: verify it by adding correct emails.

Comment: 5.1.2 The recipient address <support@mage.com info@mage.com 5.1.2 > is not a valid RFC-5321 address. m21sm455969lfh.39 - gsmtp